# Open the pod bay doors, Community

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, algorithm, vandalism

I think Community may have an algorithm issue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384378/determine-top-row-in-html-table/4384476#4384476) was flagged for attention by Community with the message "Possible vandalism of own posts; please check recent activity".  [Recent activity for this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531746/timothy-ruhle?tab=activity) doesn't show anything suspect.

Comment: I'm sorry, Will. I'm afraid we can't do that.

Comment: Does that user have a lot of deleted posts, out of curiosity? Post deletion will attract Community's flags if they do a lot of it. Though I do notice that this post doesn't have any deletions in its history, so I'm not sure exactly why it'd mark that post, but it's a shot as the Activity won't list deletions.

Comment: @Rob What's the problem?

Comment: @Pekka - I think you know what the problem is just as well as I do.

Comment: @Rob What are you talking about?

Comment: @GraceNote: Nah.  User's activity looks perfectly normal.

Comment: @Pekka this link might help you understand Rob: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/quotes,  Nevermind you seem to know already.  I missed the humor.

Comment: @jzd if you look closely at the page you linked to, you will notice that "what are you talking about?" was my line :)

Comment: @Pekka, sorry for jeopardizing the mission.  You can disconnect me now.

Comment: @jzd you must be **Community♦ in disguise!**

Comment: @Pekka, @jzd - [Conveniently, we can skip to the end.] This conversation can serve no purpose anymore. Goodbye.

Comment: +1 for strategic naming to maximize viewing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Grace Note's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82010/open-the-pod-bay-doors-community#comment-200277) is correct -- the user has deleted several of their posts in a row, which is what triggered <s>HAL</s> Community to flag this for attention. The post that was flagged was the one that crossed the threshold, so the deletion was denied and the flag inserted.

Comment: So, deletes aren't recorded in recent activity?  Also, it would be nice if your details here was included in the flag.

Comment: Oh, it denies deletion when the flag is coming up? That's kinda cool, and also explains why the post didn't have any deletion history.

Comment: @Will: Agreed; I've changed the auto-flag message accordingly.